# Passing variable into named callback

Tags: javascript, callback

OK, let's keep it simple, I have the following :

```
function loopDaLoop(){
    for (var i = 0; i < tempItemsLength; i++) {
        var product = tempItems[i];
        dust.render('product', product, addProductOrFinish);
    }
}
```

and i'd like to get the current value of i inside my callback function

```
function addProductOrFinish(err, out) {
   console.log(i); // undefined
}
```

I do know it's simple, really I do... Help?

Edit :
I know I'm supposed to use a closure so I tried and failed with this :

```
(function(i){
    dust.render('product', product, addProductOrFinish);
};(i)
```

Comment: As long as your `addProductOrFinish` function is a separate function, not inline, you can't use the closure method you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different structures that could be used to solve this problem.  The simplest is to use `.bind()` to add the desired parameter to the function call.

```
function loopDaLoop(){
    for (var i = 0; i < tempItemsLength; i++) {
        var product = tempItems[i];
        dust.render('product', product, addProductOrFinish.bind(null, i));
    }
}

function addProductOrFinish(i, err, out) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

This will cause the value of `this` to change in `addProductOrFinish` if that was important.  If so, you could work around that too, but it's not as simple.

---

Here's another approach using a closure that returns a function and preserves the value of `this` in case `dust.render()` is setting that:

```
function loopDaLoop(){
    for (var i = 0; i < tempItemsLength; i++) {
        var product = tempItems[i];
        dust.render('product', product, getAddProductOrFinish(i));
    }
}

function getAddProductOrFinish(loopArg) {
     return function(err, out) {
         return addProductOrFinish.call(this, loopArg, err, out);
     }
}

function addProductOrFinish(i, err, out) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

---

Or, if addProductOrFinish can be an inline function, then it can use the IIFE-type structure you tried like this:

```
function loopDaLoop(){
    for (var i = 0; i < tempItemsLength; i++) {
        var product = tempItems[i];
        (function(i) {
            dust.render('product', product, function(err, out) {
                console.log(i);
                // rest of your addProductOrFinish logic here
            });
        )(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought bind was just for passing this?

Comment: @xShirase - `.bind()` can also be used to add arguments.  It prepends arguments to whatever was already going to be passed.  See my example.

Comment: Awesome, I just learnt something. @jfriend00 useful as always!

Comment: @xShirase - I added two more options.